# How do I add a navigation property for a Entity Framework Complex Type

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using VS2010 Beta 2, I have a Complex Type called **Address** with the following properties:

- Street
- City
- CountryId

I have a **Country** Entity defined in my Model, but I can't seem to find a way to add a reference (Navigation Property) from the **CountryId** property of my Complex Type to the **Id** property of my **Country** entity.

I'm I going about this the wrong way or is this something that I can't do with the designer??...

Another option I have is just creating an Address entity, but it just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: The Address Complex type contains other properties, they are just not relevant at this point.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

It seems like the current version of the Entity Framework doesn't support a Navigation Property or foreign key within a Complex Type.

The other sensible option is to create a separate Address Entity, which will have all of the foreign keys it needs, and then create Navigation Properties within all my other entities.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this, because it goes against the idea of what complex types and navigation properties are. Complex types have value semantics, rather than reference identity. Navigation properties are first-class entities and have reference semantics. Therefore, they cannot be part of a complex type. As it seems you've discovered, the solution is to partition the parts with value semantics into the complex type, and add it to an entity containing the navigation properties you require.

Comment: How does this violate value semantics? The navigation property is simply a reference to an entity.

Comment: @MZywitza: You just answered your own question. If it contains a reference, it's really not a value type. See Microsoft's guidelines on value types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: The link talks about structures. Value types as in DDD are all types that don't have an identity of their own. Think of the sample in the question. It is an value type because two addresses that have the same values are interchangable regardless of whether the reference an entity or not.

Comment: DDD does not prevent a value type to reference an entity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498637/should-value-object-hold-reference-to-entity What if two addresses reference the same city? Does it make them not interchangeable? So does Hibernate supports this? Yes, almost from the beginning. Should EF support this? Absolutely and possibly it will. So, while blindly defending even a methodology like DDD is wrong, defending an implementation like EF is even worse.

Comment: @CagatayKalan: Although this post is nearly 7 years old, I'll note I was attempting to actually answer the question, not give an opinion on anything. EF 1 had a particular notion of stuff.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is possible in the newest EF versions? 
This post is 10 years after the original question was made.

Comment: @Yan EF Core 3 introduced Keyless Entity Types, which are comparable to the old EF's Complex Types, but Keyless Entity Types support much more features such as navigation properties.