# How to configure one-to-many relationship with intermediary wrapper class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 as an ORM. I'd like to configure a one-to-many relationship between the `Rule` and `Code` entities. I want to do this with an intermediary wrapper class called `RuleParameters`. In addition, I don't want this wrapper object to be represented in the DB.

Is this possible with EF? If so, what annotation / fluent api configuration am I missing?

Here's my setup. I am showing annotations here over fluent api to be concise.

```
public class Rule
{
    public Rule()
    {
        Parameters = new RuleParameters();
    }

    public int RuleId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public RuleParameters Parameters { get; set; }

}

public class RuleParameters
{
    public virtual IList<Code> Codes;
}

public Code
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }

    public int RuleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RuleId")]
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }

}
```

Problems I've encountered:

- `RuleParameters` is not an entity so I naturally want to treat it as a complex type, but can't due to the `Codes` association [(1/2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx) [(2/2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614703/how-do-i-add-a-navigation-property-for-a-entity-framework-complex-type).
- Hiding `RuleParameters` wrapper from EF while simultaneously configuring the one-to-many relationship seems contradictory.

Comment: @GertArnold `[NotMapped]` is for hiding `RuleParameters`. It seems like doing so also hides any kind of relationships I want to configure between entities however, thus the contradiction :(.

Comment: Well, you can't hide `RuleParameters`, you have to map it as a complex type, either by the fluent API, or by a data annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use an intermediate class?
Make the relationship without the intermediate class.

```
public class Rule
{
   public Rule()
   {
      Codes = new HashSet<Code>();
   }

   public int RuleId { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Code> Codes { get; set; }
}

public Code
{
   public int CodeId { get; set; }

   public int RuleId { get; set; }

   public virtual Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I omitted discussion of my design to focus on whether this problem is solvable with EF. For inquiring minds, the underlying database structure is one master table `Rule` with 10+ children tables. I'd prefer to categorize these 10+ table relations organizationally in the Rule entity rather than flatten them all out. As an example, I'd expect Rule.RuleParameters to have 4 navigation properties and another type Rule.Filters to contain 5 navigation properties. IMO the wrapper provides more context than renaming each property RuleParameterCode or RuleFilterDate.